# Which software can turn on a light if a UI notification is received?

Tags: windows, osx, notification, hardware

## Requirement

### Must

If I get an operating system UI notification message, then turn on a light.

### Should

If I get a message in a message in slack, teams, or outlook, then turn on a light.

## Constraints

### Must

- mac & windows compatible.
- available in Britain.
- local interface - no cloud account connections are permitted.

### Should

- plug-and-play - prefer to avoid software development.

## Already reviewed

- The [blink(1)](https://buy.thingm.com/blink1) might work, but I cannot see confirmation in their documentation and it is rather expensive to post to Britain.
- The [BlinkStick Nano](https://www.blinkstick.com/products/blinkstick-nano) might work, but I cannot see confirmation in their documentation.
- A [USB nightlight](https://amzn.to/3kLGIBJ) would physically do the job, but does not come with any software.

## Simple, right?

This must be a solved problem, right? I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure since I don't have hardware like that, but IFTTT came to mind first. It's listed as a service that works with the 1st one - blink1 - at the very least.

Then there's the trigger part which seems to be available for Windows 10 notifications: [PushSafer](https://ifttt.com/pushsafer) I don't know about Mac, but you can easily check that yourself by creating an account, downloading their app and setting up triggers.

Good inspiration for me to look into something similar nonetheless, it could be very useful.